# Does $f^2\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ imply $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Suppose $f^2\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

i.e. $\int |f^2|~d\lambda=\int f^2~d\lambda<\infty$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Is it true that $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What's the motivation for this question?  Can you add your own thoughts on the question?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $f^2$ is in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $f$ is in $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$, so your question is equivalent to asking whether $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

This is false, with a particular example being $$f(x) = \left\{\array{0&x\in[-1,1]\\\frac{1}{|x|}&\text{otherwise}}\right.$$

Now, $f^2(x)$ is integrable (with integral $2$), but $f$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

No, $L^2(\Bbb R)\nsubseteq L^1(\Bbb R)$. It would be the case if you were considering a space of finite measure, though.